# Issues installing PyPortfolioOpt

Tags: python, pip

Ive tried installing PyPortfolioOpt and it has not yet worked for me. I need help for how to install it. What I have done yet is that ive upgraded pip but the following error message looks like this:

Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [119 lines of output]
Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2023.12.21-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.8 kB)
Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
Using cached setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting setuptools_scm>=6.2
Using cached setuptools_scm-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Collecting qdldl
Using cached qdldl-0.1.7.post0.tar.gz (70 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Installing backend dependencies: started
Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting numpy==1.23.2 (from oldest-supported-numpy)
Using cached numpy-1.23.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (13.3 MB)
Collecting packaging>=20 (from setuptools_scm>=6.2)
Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions (from setuptools_scm>=6.2)
Using cached typing_extensions-4.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting scipy>=0.13.2 (from qdldl)
Using cached scipy-1.11.4-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata (165 kB)
Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2023.12.21-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Using cached setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Using cached setuptools_scm-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Using cached scipy-1.11.4-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl (29.7 MB)
Using cached typing_extensions-4.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: qdldl
Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
    × Building wheel for qdldl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [72 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_ext
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 81, in build_extensions
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
            return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
            with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
            self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1917, in _execute_child
            raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'
  
        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
            main()
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
            return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 404, in build_wheel
            return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 389, in _build_with_temp_dir
            self.run_setup()
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
            exec(code, locals())
          File "<string>", line 113, in <module>
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
            return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
            return run_commands(dist)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
            dist.run_commands()
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 963, in run_command
            super().run_command(command)
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/normal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
            self.run_command("build")
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 963, in run_command
            super().run_command(command)
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
            self.run_command(cmd_name)
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 963, in run_command
            super().run_command(command)
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 88, in run
            _build_ext.run(self)
          File "/private/var/folders/s7/0npkj2dn33n_y0_q_cc2d8zr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8lm050w/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run
            self.build_extensions()
          File "<string>", line 83, in build_extensions
        RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build qdldl
        [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for qdldl
  Failed to build qdldl
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for qdldl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Comment: The documentation mentions: *"Prior to installing PyPortfolioOpt, you need to install C++. On macOS, this means that you need to install XCode Command Line Tools (see here).*" Have you done that? https://pyportfolioopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation

Comment: Yes! I have done that : )